# command prompt no user input

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd, runas

I am writing a script to install a DB. I use the RunAs command in order to install the DB under DBUser user. I use a VB script which calls the runas function and then I enter the password using the sendkeys function in vbs. When I send the whole password at once

`sendkeys ("PASSWORD")`

it is giving problems with some servers so I changed the logic to enter the password by sending one letter at a time

`For k=1 To Len(PASSWORD)
WScript.Sleep 200
oShell.SendKeys Mid(PASSWORD,k,1)
Next`

I call this vbs from a batch file and when this vbs executes, it brings up another commend prompt asking for the DBUser's password.. Since the passowrd letters go one by one, the users think that they have to enter the password (which they dont) and if they try to enter the pwd, the DB install fails..

so my question is..... Is there a way that I can **disable** the new command prompt window (which opens up to enter the password) so that even if the user tries to enter anything, the cmd window wont take it.. OR is there any other way which I can use to enter the Runas password automatically in the background?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post more of the script and/or batch file? Is the sendkeys command in another script called from the batch file? oShell.Run has the option to run hidden...

Comment: Hi @langstrom .. Thanks for the reply.. I used psexec instead of runas and took care of the issue.. Thanks again